# Pivoting a VPN Connection

Tags: penetration-test, exploit, vpn

Scenario: An attacker is connected via VPN to an unknown remote host. The remote host is assumed to have two NICs, one serving the VPN and the other serving another unknown subnet. In addition, the remote host is not exploitable using other vectors such as RDP or SSH.

Question: How can the attacker pivot of the remote host? A possible first step could be to find the details of the other subnet. Such as what you would get if you could execute "ipconfig/ifconfig".

Answer (score 1):

Since it was not specified, I will address both TUN and TAP VPN servers. You can read more about the difference at the [OpenVPN wiki](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting).

Typically, a VPN server using TUN will push static routes to one or more subnets, or potentially for the entire address space, as to act as the default gateway. The client configuration file may contain information about routes, or once connected to the VPN, the attacker's routing table may be populated with information about the remote subnets. This information could be used for enumeration and scanning of hosts on those subnets.

In the case where the VPN server only pushes routes to act as the default gateway (e.g. OpenVPN's `redirect-gateway def1` option), you may have to resort to blindly performing host discovery on [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) private networks, perhaps using Nmap or another scanner.

On the other hand, a VPN server using TAP may result in the attacker receiving an address directly on the target network, so the local `tun0` interface or similar will display information about the remote subnet. The attacker can also start receiving broadcast/multicast traffic on the network, which may help with passive discovery of other hosts.